# Content provider usage for search results

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

Folks,

I have a dilemma how to architect Android application that communicates with external RESTfull service (actually OData service). The service:

- Returns list of folders
- Returns documents in a folder
- Performs search based on search options and search query
- etc...

After the presentation "[Developing Android REST client applications](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/developing-RESTful-android-apps.html)" I was convinced to implement it using Content Provider that wrapps my HTTP calls. Basically I should synchronize local DB and remote resources. 
My question is how to implement search functionality. On a server side search is a function that returns objects (JSON). Should I save these objects in a local DB?  How to use pagination in this case?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/parleys-android-nextgen/

An Android Project that covers your problem using the code of the official Google IO App (IOShed) but using JSON than XML.